# Detect closing facebook login popup by "X" button

Tags: angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using this [great](https://github.com/GoDisco/ngFacebook) module for my angularjs based app.
My question is how to detect if the user was clicked on the red "X" close button on facebook login popup? This event needs me in order to remove "waiting" loader from screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `response` argument inside `.then()` function.

If `response.status == 'unknown'` the user has clicked cancel.

**E.g.**

```
$scope.login = function() {
    $facebook.login().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status == 'unknown') {
        console.log('Cancelled');
      }
      refresh();
    });
  };
```

**[Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/kAZvaSvVB1gscxWKZ0zN?p=preview).**

Hope it helps.